# Why do I get a parse error when trying to add a background image?

Tags: css, html

My instructor requires it to be done through css.
I can't figure out where I slipped up, though I'm sure it's staring me in the face.

```
/* font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family; */

/* font: italic small-caps normal 13px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif */

body {
font: normal normal normal 14px/1.3em arial, sans-serif; 
}

h1 {
font: normal normal; padding: 1.5em;
}

li {
display: inline; 
}

.nav {
    font: normal normal bolder 30px/1.5em arial, sans-serif; background-color: #526063;
}

a {
color: #ff4300;
}

body {
background-image: url(../Project Img/camping sky.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Could be the spaces in `../Project Img/camping sky.jpg`. You could also try wrapping the path in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use quotes and then whitespace is okay. Single or double:

```
background-image: url('../Project Img/camping sky.jpg');
```